# send attachment that is created in code via python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, outlook, office-automation

```
 data1=[218031839]
    data3=[204394266]
    
    # dataframe Name and Age columns
    df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
    #Adding the header
    df.set_axis(["Bans"],axis=1,inplace=True)
    df.head()
    
    # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\user\file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    
    # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',startrow=1,index=False)
    
    
    # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
    writer.save()
    reader = pd.read_excel(r'file.xlsx')
    print(reader)
    #ss_body = ss_df1.to_html(index=False)
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = 'xyz@gmail.com';
    '
    mail.Subject = 'Report'
    mail.Body = 'testing purpose now ..Pl ignore the mail'
    mail.attachmensts.add(r'C:\user\file.xlsx')
    mail.send()

    #remove the file
    Os.remove(r'C:\user\file.xlsx')
```

getting the below:

```
os.remove(r'C:\Users\file.xlsx'')
```

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

I successfully sent the mail from Python and next step is to remove the excel from the location where it is saved on my pc. But getting the above error and can anyone look into this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method to attach a file. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment. The file name is not enough. For example, the following VBA macro shows how to use the method (the Outlook object model is common for all kind of programming languages):

```
Sub AddAttachment() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 
 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
 myAttachments.Add "D:\Test.xlsx", _ 
 olByValue, 1, "Test" 
 myItem.Display 
End Sub
```

Also there is no need to call the `Display` method right before `Send`.

Comment: can you tell me syntax as per above mentioned code and file has created within code so how can we give the system path.?

Comment: You must save the excel file to the disk and then specify the file path to the `Add` method.

Comment: Thanks .but stuck in above code. please advise

Comment: Which code exactly? To save an Excel file to the disk or specify the file path to add an attachment?

Comment: I successfully attached the document  & sent an mail after that I need remove the excel file from system.     mail.Subject = 'Report'
    mail.Body = 'testing purpose now ..Pl ignore the mail'
    mail.attachmensts.add(r'C:\user\file.xlsx')
    mail.send()

    #remove the file
    Os.remove(r'C:\user\file.xlsx')   ...but getting below erro..PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

Comment: After you are done with the file you can close the file writer and any objects that can related to the file. Also you may try to wait until the item is released/sent out.

Comment: can you tell me syntax as per mentioned code....coded writer.close()  but getting waring.

Comment: Just set to null all objects that are related to the excel file. Also you may consider handling the ItemAdd event on the Sent Items folder where you can make sure the mail was sent out and the remove the excel file. As a possible workaround you may add a timer to wait until everything is processed and then remove the file.

Comment: can you tell me syntax as per mentioned code....coded writer.close()  but getting waring.................C:\.....\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py:339: UserWarning: Calling close() on already closed file.
  warn("Calling close() on already closed file.")